# Using KeyBy vs reinterpretAsKeyedStream() when downstream task is of different parallelism

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I see this warning in the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/experimental/) of `reinterpretAsKeyedStream`

> WARNING: The re-interpreted data stream MUST already be pre-partitioned in EXACTLY the same way Flink’s keyBy would partition the data in a shuffle w.r.t. key-group assignment.

Does this mean that if we use this optimization we have to use the same parallelism value for the source stream and for the second ('consumer') stream? Would this lead to corrupt data if we use different parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in trying to use `reinterpretAsKeyedStream` if the parallelism is changing at that point in the job graph. The whole purpose of `reinterpretAsKeyedStream` is to avoid unnecessary network shuffles, and if the parallelism is changing, then every event is going to have to undergo serialization and deserialization and be sent across the network anyway.

Comment: At the onset, I assume all tasks will have the same parallelism. The point of the question is to know if there's a risk in implementing the pipeline with `reinterpretAsKeyedStream`. What will be the result, if we choose to change parallelism as a result of performance optimizations and happen leave this code in place? Will this just make `reinterpretAsKeyedStream` ineffective,  or do we face a greater risk?

Comment: I think it would be okay, but I'm not 100% certain.